# URLs with "space", "%20", "+" are canonicals?

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, url-encoding

If I have a URL encoded and another does not, e.g.

- `<a href="http://example.com/images/foo abc.jpg">Image</a>`
- `<a href="http://example.com/images/foo+abc.jpg">Image</a>`
- `<a href="http://example.com/images/foo%20abc.jpg">Image</a>`

or (using utf8)

- `<a href="http://example.com/portugal/évora">Image</a>`
- `<a href="http://example.com/portugal/%C3%A9vora">Image</a>`

They will be considered the same by *search engines*?

Answer (score 10):

Spaces in URLs should be encoded.   That would eliminate `foo abc.jpg` as the canonical.

Here is a question that addresses how the space should be encoded:  [In a URL, should spaces be encoded using %20 or +?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211229/in-a-url-should-spaces-be-encoded-using-20-or)  Spaces may only be encoded as a `+` in the query string portion of the URL, so that eliminates the `foo+abc.jpg` as the canonical.

Your canonical URL for the space should be `foo%20abc.jpg`

For URLs with non-ASCII UTF-8 characters, the *real* URL is always the encoded one.   Browsers typically only display the URL with non-ASCII characters in the address bar. If you copy and paste the URL out, you will get the encoded version.   For example see: https://www.dmoz.org/World/Thai/%E0%B8%9A%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%99/

[image]

That makes your canonical URL: `%C3%A9vora`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry still not quite understand, I refer only to the search engines. I need to know if they are considered canonicals links. Sorry if I did not understand something.

Comment: Search engines will take their cues from the specs and browser behavior.  You need to choose which URL you treat as canonical and I have pointed you to the ones that the search engines are most likely to support.